# How to upload image to strapi?

Tags: express, graphql, koa, strapi, vue-apollo

### How can I upload images to Strapi server?

- I use the GraphQL plugin.
- I prefer a single endpoint for all of API

[I found an article about how to manage file uploads but I have some questions](https://medium.com/@danielbuechele/file-uploads-with-graphql-and-apollo-5502bbf3941e)

**Do I need to convert my image to a Base64 string?**

My production server will be PostgreSQL. I was planning to store images as Blob. But now it turns out I can only send Form-Data to Strapi servers.

**Do I need something like [apollo-upload-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-upload-client)?**

**Note**: Currently I use vue-apollo and nativescript-vue as frontend.

```js
import VueApollo from "vue-apollo";
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, HttpLink } from "apollo-boost";
import { setContext } from "apollo-link-context";
```

Comment: https://morioh.com/p/20e376ed62fb has a tutorial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to upload files with GraphQL, I suggest you check this gist - https://gist.github.com/alexandrebodin/fedc71c8513bfbb6283cc90ae62755c5

You should have all the information you need to achieve that.

Comment: link to gist is broken

Comment: I am trying understand react code. Upload

The Upload scalar type represents a file upload.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answer of @Jim LAURIE I made my node work:

```js
import { GraphQLClient, gql } from "graphql-request"
import { createReadStream } from "fs";

[...]

  const endpoint = 'http://localhost:1337/graphql';

  const graphQLClient = new GraphQLClient(endpoint, {
    headers: {
      authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}`,
    },
  });

  try {
    const data = await graphQLClient.request( gql`
    mutation($file: Upload!) {
      upload(file: $file) {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  `, {
      file: createReadStream(__dirname + '/Strapi/test/picture.jpg') // ⚠ Ensure path is correct or the stream will never send data and you will have Socket Hang out error
  });

    console.info("ID of file:" + data.upload.id);
    console.info(data)
    console.info("data")
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    console.error("error")
  }
```

If you don't know how get the JWT [check the units testing docs of Strapi](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/guides/unit-testing.html#testing-auth-endpoint-controller), translate to GraphQL should be easy.